# Significance of Group keywords in Apache pig word count program

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, word-count

i am a beginner to pig and i have started with the word count program.

In the following word count program, i see group keyword being used in 3rd and 4th lines. Is the usage of the keyword 'group' same or different at both the places as i am a bit confused as the group in the 4th line of the program is throwing error when given in Caps?

```
lines = LOAD '/user/root/pig/pig_demo.txt' AS (line:chararray);
words = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
grouped = GROUP words BY word;
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);
DUMP wordcount;
```

Answer (score 0):

They both are different.The former i.e. "GROUP" is an operator where as the latter i.e. "group" is a keyword referring to the GROUP Key.

Below is the explanation from [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP).

**The GROUP operator groups together tuples that have the same group key (key field)**. The key field will be a tuple if the group key has more than one field, otherwise it will be the same type as that of the group key. The result of a GROUP operation is a relation that includes one tuple per group. This tuple contains two fields:

***The first field is named "group" (do not confuse this with the GROUP operator)*** and is the same type as the group key.
The second field takes the name of the original relation and is type bag.
The names of both fields are generated by the system as shown in the example below.
Note that the GROUP (and thus COGROUP) and JOIN operators perform similar functions. GROUP creates a nested set of output tuples while JOIN creates a flat set of output tuples.